# How can I put a question mark at the end of the edittext as in quora?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

How can I add question mark(?) at the end of the EditText as user type into it. On every textchanged question mark should remain at the end of the edittext just like it is happen in Quora. I am using the textwatcher to change the text and place the question mark at the end but I am not getting the exact logic.

```
textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            questionTxt.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
            questionTxt.setText(questionTxt.getText().toString().replace("?", ""));
            questionTxt.setSelection(questionTxt.getText().length()-1);
            questionTxt.setText(questionTxt.getText().toString()+"?");
            questionTxt.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
            questionTxt.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            questionTxt.setSelection(editable.length());
            if (questionTxt.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
                questionTxt.setError("Enter question");
        }
    };

    questionTxt.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Please refer below Image for reference.

[image]

Comment: What happen if you put your (?) symbol at afterTextChanged() method ?

Comment: It gets added but next time when I again press the key this (?) will remain at its older position and the new question mark gets added. And It repeats as i type into edittext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to obtain that is to create `TextWatcher` just like this:

```
textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        if (editable.length() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        String text = editable.toString();
        int indexOfQuestionMark = text.lastIndexOf("?");
        if (indexOfQuestionMark == -1 || indexOfQuestionMark != text.length() - 1) {
            editable.append("?");
        }
    }
};

questionTxt.setHint("Enter question")
questionTxt.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

With little tuning your solution should work perfectly :)

I've set a hint instead of setting error in question txt. This way user will see text "Enter question" when nothing is entered.

"Alghoritm" is searching for '?' occurence in non empty input. If it is at the end -> then nothing to do. If it is not found, or is found somewhere inside text -> then question mark is added in the end.

Notice that this TextWatcher implementation is not dependent on questionTxt so you can put it in another file.

Comment: gaskoin It is still not working. It is showing questionmark after every character I type :|

Comment: because EditText sets cursor position at the end after TextWatcher launches "afterTextChanged" method. So you should force it to be placed before the last character (questionTxt.setSelection(editable.length() - 2)). On my phone it is not occuring so I did not post a code that does it. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your super awesome solution

Comment: just put a edittext.setSelection(text.length()); under .append

Answer (score 0):

This might help you..

```
boolean flag=true;
questionTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            AskBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#022B69"));
            if (editable.length() == 0) {
                return;
            }
            if (flag){
                String text = editable.toString();
                int indexOfQuestionMark = text.lastIndexOf("?");
                if (indexOfQuestionMark == -1 || indexOfQuestionMark != text.length() - 1) {
                    editable.append("?");
                    questionTxt.setSelection(1);
                    flag=false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

"Alghoritm" is searching for '?' occurence in non empty input. If it is at the end -> then nothing to do. If it is not found, or is found somewhere inside text -> then question mark is added in the end.

Notice that this TextWatcher implementation is not dependent on questionTxt so you can put it in another file.

So if you see there is setselection method that basically points the cursor to a particular point.

Also flag variable is for stoping the appending "?" question mark again and again....

Answer (score -1):

This code prevents adding a question mark every char being inputted, also clears the question mark once there is nothing inside the Edittext.

```
public void addQuestionMark(final EditText et){

        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.length() == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                if("?".equals(s.toString())){
                    s.clear();
                    return;
                }

                String text = s.toString();
                int indexOfQuestionMark = text.lastIndexOf("?");
                if (indexOfQuestionMark == -1 || indexOfQuestionMark != text.length() - 1) {
                    s.append("?");
                    et.setSelection(s.length()-1);
                }
            }

        });
    }
```